# Update text field in webpage with vba excel

Tags: html, vba, excel

I want to update text box in webpage with the values in excel sheet. I am unable to update for one of the fields in webpage I think because of **"keypress event"**. Below is the HTML code:

```
            <td width="250" valign="middle"><font class="bold">NTFS</font></td>
            <td colspan="2" width="215" valign="bottom">
                <input type="textbox"  onKeyPress="NumericKeyPress(event);" OnChange="HandleOnChange();" OnBlur="HandleTrim(this);CheckChanges(this,'');" 
                    name="txtBillNTFS" value="" maxlength=10 size=45 >
            </td>
```

---

And below is the vba code which is not doing the work:

```
Set iedoc = ie.document

   For i = 2 To k

With iedoc.forms(0)

Worksheets("Update").Select
iedoc.all.txtBillNTFS.Value = Cells(i, "c").Value
  ie.document.getElementById("cmdUpdate").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following codeline:

```
ie.Document.getElementsByName("txtBillNTFS")(0).Value = Worksheets("Update").Range("C" & i).Value
```

Also include the frame names (not form name) if any in above line. I am unable to get the frame names from the html lines you provided.

Comment: What is meant by frame name? I am new to HTML so I am not aware of that. Just by replacing the above lines I am still not able to work out with the code.

Comment: Webpage you are working on might be divided in frames. Without looking at the actual webpage it is difficult to help with perfect code line.

Comment: Because of security I cant post everything of the website. Is there any alternate way I can update the fields or some specific HTML code I can provide you with.

Comment: I may be able to help, if you post the HTML source code of whole page.